# IE10 Bootstrap 3.2 col-pull bug with full height columns

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In IE10 and IE11 columns change position when the columns are given a full height hack (large bottom padding, large minus bottom margin)

See Codepen here - http://cdpn.io/HpJzB

Any ideas on this would be very helpful. The only one I've worked out so far is to put a float right on the last column for min-width:1200px media query. But I'd love to know if anyone has any insight on why this is happening.

BTW you'll need to uncomment the second media query to get the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Because the media queries are from smallest to largest in the min width. Stacking order.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/guymA